# Cannot restore Dropout using get_tensor_by_name

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensor, dropout

I tried to save and restore some tensors.

In saving session:

```
...
self.abc = tf.reduce_sum(self.element_wise_product, 2, name="abc")
self.def= tf.nn.dropout(abc, self.dropout_keep[0], name="def")
...
```

After saving, I tried to restore the session

```
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
weight_saver.restore(sess, save_file)

pretrain_graph = tf.get_default_graph()
abc= pretrain_graph.get_tensor_by_name('abc:0')
def = pretrain_graph.get_tensor_by_name('def:0')
```

But I got the error:

> "The name 'def:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The
>   operation, 'def', does not exist in the graph."

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `tf.nn.dropout(abc, self.dropout_keep[0], name="def")` is a Tensorflow operation and not a node in the graph that you can restore per se.

Besides, I would restore the nodes in the graph that I want execute, for example the `logits` node so that I can get the output of the model and the `input` nodes so that I can pour data in the Model. Therefore, I see no reason to restore the `dropout` node.

Comment: Thank Gorjan, I also suspect about that. Can you suggest a solution to restoring the dropout? Or do you think it is not really necessary as nodes are enough?